# What can be done in Cpython that can not be done in IronPython?

Tags: python, ironpython

What can be done in Cpython that can not be done in IronPython?

Comment: The obvious: Run on a platform which doesn't know or care about .NET or Mono?

Comment: oh my, my pants are wet with the laughter.

Comment: Opps, sorry just read it again, my tiny little British cynical mind kicked in and thought you were being insulting :) I do apologize.

Comment: No apologies needed, but yeah, I wasn't trying to be insulting, funny or even "smart alec"-ish, just stating an obvious answer, in a comment (didn't think it had its place among proper answers, yet thought it worth of notice.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are writing "100% pure Python", you can do everything that CPython can do in IronPython.  The problem comes in when you want to use a third-party package.  Many of them will have written their performance-intensive portions in C, and rely on the Python/C API (e.g. NumPy).

As a glue language for hooking together .NET components, IronPython is great.

Comment: I don't get IronPython as a glue language. I would want to use python for what it can do, and for what it is. Just need to know any gottachas before delving into IronPython. On the plus side, IronPython  gets round the GIL :)

Comment: Depending on your needs, you may find the multiprocessing standard module sufficient, as it can get around the GIL too.

Comment: It does. think that they are fixing the GIL as we speak.